# Is there a way to define an integer property as int64 in a Joi model that is used by Hapi Swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger, hapi.js, joi, hapi-swagger

I am having the following `Joi` model

```
const SimpleModel = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.number().integer().required().description('ID')
}).label('SimpleModel');
```

The model is being used in the `@hapi/hapi` route below

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: `/api/v1.0/data`,
    handler: () => { id: 1 }, // a mock handler
    config: {
        plugins: {
            'hapi-swagger': {
                responses: {
                    200: {
                        description: 'OK',
                        schema: SimpleModel
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above model is generated as shown the below swagger definition

```
swagger: '2.0'
host: localhost:8080
basePath: /api
info: 
  title: 'Swagger for SimpleModel'
  version: '1.0'
schemes:
  - http
  - https
paths:
  /v1.0/data:
    get:
      summary: Returns an object
      responses:
        '200':
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/SimpleModel'
          description: OK
definitions:
  SimpleModel:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        description: ID
    required:
      - id
```

What I want is to add an additional field to `id`, which is `format: int64`, e.g.

```
definitions:
  SimpleModel:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64 # <-- new field here!
        description: ID
    required:
      - id
```

While this is supported by swagger, I cannot find any way to define it in my `Joi` model so that it will appear in the generated swagger by `hapi-swagger`.

I am searching online for days but I haven't been able to find anything helpful on the web, either a documentation or an example.

Is there a way to include `format: int64` in the generated swagger of `SimpleModel`?

Comment: Without extending hapi-swagger yourself I don't think this is possible from looking at [how it parses numbers](https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/blob/v14.2.5/lib/properties.js#L365-L384).

Comment: @Ankh thanks for pointing out the correct function. By writing some extra code in `parseNumber` I can get the desired result. The drawback here is that it requires to keep locally a modified version of `hapi-swagger`. I am looking to see if `hapi-swagger` provides some way to extend or override its default functionality, but so far no luck.

Comment: The main question is actually if you're restricted in anything currently concerning the number range smaller than int64.

Comment: @David the need for this came from a third party that uses the swagger model definition to automatically generate classes (I think in Java). This automated process defines the properties as `Integer` and when there is a long value (e.g. epoch), they cannot serialize the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "71422008",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/hapi": "^20.2.1",
    "@hapi/inert": "^6.0.5",
    "@hapi/vision": "^6.1.0",
    "blipp": "^4.0.2",
    "hapi-swagger": "^14.2.5",
    "joi": "^17.6.0",
    "qs": "^6.10.3"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```js
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const Joi = require('joi');
const Blipp = require('blipp');
const Inert = require('@hapi/inert');
const Vision = require('@hapi/vision');
const HapiSwagger = require('hapi-swagger');
const HapiSwaggerProperties = require('hapi-swagger/lib/properties');

const _parseNumber = HapiSwaggerProperties.prototype.parseNumber;
HapiSwaggerProperties.prototype.parseNumber = function(property, joiObj) {
  let _property = _parseNumber.apply(this, [property, joiObj]);
  _property.format = 'int64';
  return _property;
}
const SimpleModel = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.number().integer().required().description('ID')
}).label('SimpleModel');

const ser = async () => {
  const swaggerOptions = {
    info: {
      title: 'Test API Documentation',
      description: 'This is a sample example of API documentation.'
    }
  };

  const server = Hapi.Server({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
  });

  await server.register([
    Inert,
    Vision,
    Blipp,
    {
      plugin: HapiSwagger,
      options: swaggerOptions
    }
  ]);

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: `/api/v1.0/data`,
    options: {
      handler: () => { id: 1 }, // a mock handler
      tags: ['api'],
      plugins: {
        'hapi-swagger': {
          responses: {
            200: {
              description: 'OK',
              schema: SimpleModel
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  });

  await server.start();
  return server;
};

ser()
  .then((server) => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${server.info.uri}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Output:

```json
...
    "definitions": {
        "SimpleModel": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "ID",
                    "format": "int64"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "id"
            ]
        }
    }
...
```

---

Example 2 with custom types:

```
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const Joi = require('joi');
const Blipp = require('blipp');
const Inert = require('@hapi/inert');
const Vision = require('@hapi/vision');
const HapiSwagger = require('hapi-swagger');
const HapiSwaggerProperties = require('hapi-swagger/lib/properties');

const custom = Joi.extend(joi => ({
  type: 'number',
  base: Joi.number().$_setFlag('type', 'integer').$_setFlag('format', 'int64'),
  rules: {
    i32: {
      method(first, second) {
        return this.$_setFlag('type', 'integer').$_setFlag('format', 'int32');
      }
    }
  }
}));

const _parseNumber = HapiSwaggerProperties.prototype.parseNumber;
HapiSwaggerProperties.prototype.parseNumber = function(property, joiObj) {
  let _property = _parseNumber.apply(this, [property, joiObj]);

  const describe = joiObj.describe();
  if (describe.flags) {
    if (describe.flags.format) {
      _property.format = describe.flags.format;
    }

    if (describe.flags.type) {
      _property.type = describe.flags.type;
    }
  }
  return _property;
}

const SimpleModel = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.number().integer().required().description('ID'),
    seconds: custom.number().i32(),
    epochSeconds: custom.number(),
}).label('SimpleModel');

const ser = async () => {
  const swaggerOptions = {
    info: {
      title: 'Test API Documentation',
      description: 'This is a sample example of API documentation.'
    }
  };

  const server = Hapi.Server({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
  });

  await server.register([
    Inert,
    Vision,
    Blipp,
    {
      plugin: HapiSwagger,
      options: swaggerOptions
    }
  ]);

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: `/api/v1.0/data`,
    options: {
      handler: () => { id: 1 }, // a mock handler
      tags: ['api'],
      plugins: {
        'hapi-swagger': {
          responses: {
            200: {
              description: 'OK',
              schema: SimpleModel
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  });

  await server.start();
  return server;
};

ser()
  .then((server) => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${server.info.uri}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Output:

```
...
    "definitions": {
        "SimpleModel": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "ID"
                },
                "seconds": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "epochSeconds": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "id"
            ]
        }
    }
...
```

---

Example 3 with custom types and meta properties:

```
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const Hoek = require('@hapi/hoek');
const Joi = require('joi');
const Blipp = require('blipp');
const Inert = require('@hapi/inert');
const Vision = require('@hapi/vision');
const HapiSwagger = require('hapi-swagger');
const HapiSwaggerProperties = require('hapi-swagger/lib/properties');

const custom = Joi.extend(joi => ({
  type: 'int',
  base: Joi.number().meta({
    'type': 'integer',
    'format': 'int32',
  }),
  rules: {
    i64: {
      method(first, second) {
        return this.meta({
          'type': 'integer',
          'format': 'int64',
        });
      }
    }
  }
}));

const _parsePropertyMetadata = HapiSwaggerProperties.prototype.parsePropertyMetadata;
HapiSwaggerProperties.prototype.parsePropertyMetadata = function(property, name, parent, joiObj) {
  let _property = _parsePropertyMetadata.apply(this, [property, name, parent, joiObj]);

  const _type = Hoek.reach(joiObj, 'type');
  if (!this.propertyMap[_type]) {
    delete _property['x-meta']
  }

  let xMeta = Hoek.reach(joiObj, '$_terms.metas');
  xMeta = xMeta.length > 0 ? xMeta[xMeta.length - 1] : undefined;
  if (xMeta) {
    if (xMeta.type) {
      _property.type = xMeta.type;
    }

    if (xMeta.format) {
      _property.format = xMeta.format;
    }
  }

  return _property;
}

const SimpleModel = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.number().integer().required().description('ID'),
    seconds: custom.int(),
    epochSeconds: custom.int().i64(),
}).label('SimpleModel');

const ser = async () => {
  const swaggerOptions = {
    info: {
      title: 'Test API Documentation',
      description: 'This is a sample example of API documentation.'
    }
  };

  const server = Hapi.Server({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
  });

  await server.register([
    Inert,
    Vision,
    Blipp,
    {
      plugin: HapiSwagger,
      options: swaggerOptions
    }
  ]);

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: `/api/v1.0/data`,
    options: {
      handler: () => { id: 1 }, // a mock handler
      tags: ['api'],
      plugins: {
        'hapi-swagger': {
          responses: {
            200: {
              description: 'OK',
              schema: SimpleModel
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  });

  await server.start();
  return server;
};

ser()
  .then((server) => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${server.info.uri}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

```
...
    "definitions": {
        "SimpleModel": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "ID"
                },
                "seconds": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "epochSeconds": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "id"
            ]
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, and rather nicely I would say. The other missing piece of the puzzle is how we can set with `Joi` which properties we want to be int64. From what I searched so far, `Joi` doesn't support this either. But, we could use `meta()` to pass this, e.g. `id: Joi.number().integer().required().description('ID').meta({ format: 'int64' })` and take it from there

Answer (score 0):

With the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71422008/is-there-a-way-to-define-an-integer-property-as-int64-in-a-joi-model-that-is-use#comment126364421_71422008) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71593495/2851870) I got, I was able to submit a pull request to `hapi-swagger`'s repository.

So, from version v14.3.0, the following `Joi` model definition will give the desired result

```js
const SimpleModel = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.number().integer().required().description('ID').meta({ format: 'int64' })
}).label('SimpleModel');
```

```yaml
definitions:
  SimpleModel:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
        description: ID
    required:
      - id
```